# How to plot the decibel level of the sound in the atmosphere using iPhone's inbuilt mic, without recording the sound?

Tags: iphone

I want to plot the decibel level of the sound in the atmosphere that hearing through the iPhone's inbuilt mic. I don't want to record the sound to plot. I want a sound level indicator, with a graph that frequently indicates the decibel level with respect to the sound. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.politepix.com/2010/06/18/decibel-metering-from-an-iphone-audio-unit/

Comment: how to convert the resultant values into decibels? I want to get the avg and peak values in decibels.... Is there any way?

Comment: It's right in the link: "NSLog(@"decibel level is %f", decibels);" IF you like my answer would you be so kind as to click the checkbox to the left of it, indicating you've accepted it as the answer to your question?

Comment: sorry steve, i didn't know that.

Comment: @ProudMember - Working fine for me.