# Is it possible to get the sound pressure from the microphone in an iOS app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio

Is there a way to get the sound pressure (in μPa) or the sound pressure level (in dB) from the microphone of the device (as precise as possible)?

I thought of using `AVAudioRecorder` with `file:///dev/null` as URL, but I couldn't find a method returning the current sound pressure (level).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect ambient sound level on the iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687412/how-to-detect-ambient-sound-level-on-the-iphone)

Comment: See also [How to plot the decibel level of the sound in the atmosphere using iPhone's inbuilt mic, without recording the sound?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476016/how-to-plot-the-decibel-level-of-the-sound-in-the-atmosphere-using-iphones-inbu), which seems to link to some tutorials for this.

Comment: did you get it?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like that(found in iphone dev forum):

```
[avRecorder updateMeters];
float level = [avRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
```

Comment: That is the peak power, not the sound pressure.